# Why is my camera not centered?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've noticed that the `camera` property my `SKScene` is `nil`. I remedied that by creating a `SKCameraNode` setting that equal to the `camera` property, setting its `position` and adding it to the scene. However, when I do this all of a sudden my objects are no longer in the center of the scene. They are all shifted in some way that does not make sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
/*
        // This is the problem code
        let cam = SKCameraNode()
        cam.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        self.camera = cam
        self.addChild(cam)
*/
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        self.addChild(sprite)

    }
}
```

Object appears in middle of scene, as expected.

[image: Object in middle, as expected]

Now the object is shifted to the left. Why?

[image: Object shifted to the left]

**UPDATE**

The following code is giving me the behavior I want. The key is to reposition the camera every time the size of the `SKScene` changes. Thanks for the suggestions, they got me on the right track.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didChangeSize(oldSize: CGSize) {
        if let view = self.view{
            camera?.position = convertPointFromView(view.center)
        }
    }

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let cam = SKCameraNode()
        cam.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY)
        self.camera = cam
        self.addChild(cam)
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work if your scene is the same size as the view when `didMoveToView` is called. As a test, add `scaleMode = .ResizeFill` to `didMoveToView` and replace `CGPoint(self.frame.midX, self.frame.midY)` with `view.center`.

Comment: Excellent! That worked. Thank you.

Comment: The only problem here is what happens if the view was re-sized due to auto-constraints? (Which is what the original problem here is)  Instead you should be overriding the `frame` property on the scene, and on the `didSet` method, point the camera to the center of the scene, not the view.  Now your camera is always in the center of the scene

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: Overriding the frame property does not appear to be an option, since it is a read-only property and can't change. At least that's what Xcode says. But I think I can achieve what you're suggesting in the `didChangeSize` callback.